# How add pin on map?

Tags: iphone, google-maps, mkmapview, mkpinannotationview

I have a view in which i have a map. On that view i have a tool bar. In tool bar i have a button for drop pin on map. Now i want to get methods for detecting pin drop and latitude and longitude of that point. For example when user click on button then a pin drop on center of map view. And when user click on pin then show title as the address of that point where that pin drop. What function i use for that so that i can set that event on my map view? How do that?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2847/introduction-to-mapkit-on-ios-tutorial

Comment: this question from stack overflow should help you..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471361/drop-pin-in-center-of-the-screen-mkmapview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this 2 question from stack overflow should help you..

[Drop pin in center of the screen, MKMapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471361/drop-pin-in-center-of-the-screen-mkmapview)

[How to add a push pin to a MKMapView(IOS) when touching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959994/how-to-add-a-push-pin-to-a-mkmapviewios-when-touching/3960754#3960754)