# xcode iOS, Displaying user locations retrieved from parse Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

At the moment my application allows users to first save a location, called an `event` to **Parse**. Then the user can press a button to retrieve all of the stored locations from **Parse**, which are put into an array using the following code:

```
-(void) retrieveEventsFromParse {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"events"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        eventsArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: objects];
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %lu locations.", (unsigned long)objects.count);
            // Do something with the found objects
            for (PFObject *object in objects) {

                NSString *location = [object objectForKey:@"location"];
                NSLog(@"object with id %@ has location %@", object.objectId, location);

            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
}
```

I am having trouble, however, displaying these retrieved locations as pins on a map. I was wondering how would I turn one of the array objects (example below) into a pin on the map.

`\"<-27.47143300,+153.02720500> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 6/26/15, 9:47:11 AM Australian Eastern Standard Time\";\n}"`

I thought of using Regex to cut out long,lat but I honestly have no idea as to how to approach this. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: the output you have shown is not an array. Is that a string? Where did it come from in your code? Show what your "location" key looks like

Comment: I thought the output was a string, but it turned out to be a PFObject. So I converted it to a string and cut the lat-long coords out to use with Lucas' suggestion. What I posted, by the way, was one element of array (which contained about 30 of those).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at how to use `PFGeoPoint` instead of storing them as `NSString`. Then, you can access the latitude and longitude by calling the property of a valid instance of `PFGeoPoint`. The following is from `PFGeoPoint` docs:

```
/*!
 @abstract Latitude of point in degrees. Valid range is from `-90.0` to `90.0`.
 */
@property (nonatomic, assign) double latitude;

/*!
 @abstract Longitude of point in degrees. Valid range is from `-180.0` to `180.0`.
 */
@property (nonatomic, assign) double longitude;
```

As for how to put pin onto the map, these two posts should be helpful:

[Drop pin in center of the screen, MKMapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471361/drop-pin-in-center-of-the-screen-mkmapview)

[How to add a push pin to a MKMapView(IOS) when touching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959994/how-to-add-a-push-pin-to-a-mkmapviewios-when-touching/3960754#3960754)